# Pros and Cons of Isotope templates (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, erb

[Isotope](https://github.com/elado/isotope) lets you write templates in javascript. These templates can then be rendered by either the client (using plain-old javascript) or on the server (using [Johnson](https://github.com/jbarnette/johnson)).

The benefit is DRYer code. When updating the DOM on an ajax or web socket update, you can don't have to write a new partial...just point it to the one you already wrote.

Has anyone used this?

Comment: It might be helpful if you try to explain what you are trying to accomplish and if you have a more specific question.

Comment: I'm using the Jammit gem which takes the 2nd approach described on the git page.  We're forced to duplicate erb and jst views.  I haven't had much luck with SO as a forum for tech maturity, but I'm curious to see what comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I would have to try it, however , and I know not a lot of people do it, but I actually use HAML to template .js files. Although there is still that problem the author mentions , of each request being templated on the server and sending back html, unless you are sending loads of kb, or you have really, really high load site I don't think it's such a big deal.

Also ideally you shouldn't be even sending html data back and force, just JSON objects, which are rendered on the page by your ajax request. The only legitimate use I can see for this is if you have heavily ajax website, such as where you load a page once, and the you just keeping doing ajax requests for all interaction and javascript to manipulate view.

So it would help if you would clarify the final goal. Is this for some internal app where you control user environment ( you know for sure which browsers they will use, and that they will have fast enough computers to manipulate all this javascript?) Or is it going to be an app targeted towards 3rd world, where people don't have yet resources available to use all that fancy javascript.

All that said, it's an interesting concept, and I will try it our myself, to see how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

This uses Johnson, which last I checked did not work on Ruby 1.9. So that might hint at some of the immaturity of this particular solution. Eventually the community will come up with something that works really well.

One approach I have used is to make 2 completely separate templates, but try to make them as similar as possible so that it is easy to port changes from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad idea. In an Ajax application, I believe that the server should be responsible for rendering all display text. This makes i18n easier, and concentrates everything in one place. The JavaScript should simply receive data from the server, with all display text already rendered, and put it in the appropriate DOM object.

In other words, I believe that in an Ajax application, the need for a JS template engine is itself a design smell.

The situation is different in exclusively client-side JS applications, of course.